# Detect Browser clicks other than the window object

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to listen click events other than the window object? I got this problem when I found airbnb user nav menu triggers when click on anywhere in the browser. Even click on the windows taskbar. Is this possible with javascript?

[image]

Comment: can you share your code ?

Comment: No. I'm just thinking how to do that if I have to code it.

Comment: "taskbar"? What is that in a browser?

Comment: I mean windows taskbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can listen to specific `element` `click` event rather than the whole window by adding a `click` listener to the `element`

Here's the example of it:

index.html

```
<button id="button">button</button>
```

script.js

```
const buttonEl = document.getElementById("#button")
buttonEl.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // handle click
})
```

Edit: I haven't tried it, but i think you can reproduce similar action by using [blur event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event).

Here's an example:

```
document.addEventListener('blur', function(){console.log('document blur')});
window.addEventListener('blur', function(){console.log('window blur')});
```

Comment: but then the listener will fire only when click on that button. not anywhere in the browser

Comment: so you want to listen to ```click``` event everywhere within the page ?

Comment: Yep. The Airbnb user nav menu trigger even clicks on the address bar or taskbar

Comment: I've edited my answer. You can use blur event for that. Try to add ```window.addEventListener('blur', function() {console.log('blur')})``` to AirBnb console and see the log when you change browser tab

Comment: Oh how stupid I am.. That's the thing my Friend.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use an overlay technique like below:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
const nav = document.querySelector("#nav");
const overlay = document.querySelector("#overlay");

let open = false;

function changeState() {
    if ((open = !open)) {
        nav.style.display = "block";
        overlay.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        nav.style.display = "none";
        overlay.style.display = "none";
    }
}

btn.onclick = () => {
    changeState();
};

overlay.onclick = () => {
    changeState();
};
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
    padding: 20px;
}

#container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

#btn {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 46px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

#nav {
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    width: max-content;
    display: none;
    z-index: 10000;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 5px;
    padding: 5px
}

ul > li {
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

#overlay {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <main>
            <div id="container">
                <button id="btn">&equiv;</button>
                
                <div id="overlay"></div>
                
                <nav id="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li>item 1</li>
                        <li>item 2</li>
                        <li>item 3</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </main>
        
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**you may change the overlay color to be fully transparent if you want...**